# Misc. files that I can't find but that take up about a half of available storage

Tags: applications, storage, files

I have the following problem: about half of my phone storage is filled by files that grouped as Misc in Android Storage app. The problem is that I can't find these files. If I open the Misc. category there is no files displayed that can fill up that much space (the same thing goes for ES File Explorer SD card analyst).

So the question is how I can find this files.
(I have a suspicion that it's some kind of remnants from BOINC application,  but this is not helping me in any way)

[image: Storage screenshot from Android] [image: Inside of the Misc. category]
[image: Info about taken space from ES explorer]

<sup>Storage screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Here should've been another image to illustrate the situation with analysis from ES File Explorer SD card analyst, but I don't have enough karma for that.

Comment: Feel free adding the URL to the 3rd screenshot as comment (after uploading it to imgur). Someone with sufficient "karma" then can integrate it for you. // One more suspicions are "tombstones", we've had that here before. Our [storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info) might give you additional pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dandroid+diskusage&pcampaignid=APPU_1_Ill1VqDdLIHcUqywuagF) app (free), it shows detailed information about memory usage and also gives you option to:

- Scan internal or external SD and graphically display space occupied by directories/ sub directories
- Choose files / sub directories / directories for deletion
- Re-Scan after deletion so that you can free up desired storage space

[image]

Comment: You could give more info as to what the app does rather than pointing us there?

Comment: i attached picture to describe app usage

Comment: @beeshyams thnx

Comment: Oh, I guess this helped. As I understand the ES explorer were showing this data, but it was not accounting for "Applications data" and correspondingly I was getting an impression of data that is there but not displayed.
Storage app on the other was confusing in another way.
This app is accounting for all of it and it seems that all the data is legitimate after all.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these possibilities:

- Do you have "Recycle Bin" enabled in ES Explorer? If so, check the Recycle Bin folder. Its easy to forget sometimes that your deleted files aren't actually deleted when using ES.
- If you wiped-clean or reset your phone to factory recently, it might be keeping your previous data somewhere, normally in a `.android` folder somewhere.
- Also you can enable to show hidden files in ES Explorer, maybe might give hints.
- ES Cleaner too, run it and see what it finds and thinks you can clear. Most times, it provides the link to the directory where the files tantamount to cleaning are.

I can think of the above now. I hope it helps